# Get application name on focus in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am new in blackberry. I want the name of the application on focus. That is, for a particular application, if it is focused in downloads folder then name of that application should be displayed. Is it possible in Blackberry?

Please share it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project you will find a file called BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml

If you open that file in eclipse you will see it allows you to set 2 icons and tick one as rollover (in focus).

You could simply design the rollover icon so that it incorporates your applications name. Or maybe logo/initials as it's not very big.

I'm guessing you mean when your application icon is in focus, if you mean other peoples applications then the answer is no (or more specifically what Richard said).

Comment: Thanks Ray. It is working fine. Now, how to get application name as the icon image is changed on focus? For now, I only want to display application name in console. Please help me.

Comment: Is my assumption about the application being yours correct? If yes, you will already know the applications name and I assume you can write console output on the emulator. Is this an accurate re-wording of your question? "How can a BlackBerry application detect when its launcher icon is focused?"

Answer (score 1):

This would only be possable if the application in question either provided an API for other applications to get this data, through a listener interface for example; or if it issued a global event.

Comment: Hey Rechard, I don't understand what you are saying. Please give me more details through any code example if you have. It may helpful to me. Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: In order to do that I need you to be more specific. What do you mean by "if it is focused in downloads folder"? If you mean the the home screen icon cursor rolls over the application icon, then as Ray said there is no way to do this. Also, what do you mean by "then name of that application should be displayed."? Displayed by what application? Where?

Comment: Yes Rechard, It should be displayed by that application only. And for now, It should be displayed in console. That's enough and fine. Actually, I want to override downloads folder's DELETE menu for that particular application, exactly when it is focused. Thank you so much for your support.

Comment: Is this another attempt at preventing deletion of your application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910285/delete-blackberry-app-with-password-closed If so, the only way you can keep an application on the BlackBerry against the users wishes is through BES policy. Unless you can come up with a very good reason to prevent a user from deleting your app from his BlackBerry you're not going to get any help from me.